# How can I fix _TypeError in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, typeerror, fluttermap

I have a trivial map like this:

```
  Map _datiMap = box.get("exc") ?? {};
```

when it runs:

```
_datiMap.addAll({"${DateFormat("y-MM-dd", "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.codice}").format(_giornoSelezionato)}" : "${_oreProgrammateGiornoAttuale! + 1}"});
```

throws this error:

```
type '_Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' of 'other'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicity state the `Map` type like

```
Map<String, dynamic> _datiMap = box.get("exc") ?? {};
```

Comment: still throws the same error. Dynamic should by itself include all types, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to ["improvements" in Dart's type handling.](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems)

I agree, with Map<dynamic, dynamic> being passed to a Map<String, dynamic>, as long as the key is a String, why error?  However, the decision was made to enforce explicit type declaration and not infer.

So, you'll need to write `Map<String, dynamic>.from(value)` to pass value to a Map<String, dynamic>.

To specifically answer your question, I presume your Map was inferred to be a Map<String, dynamic>, so you need to write:

```
_datiMap.addAll(Map<String, dynamic>.from({"${DateFormat("y-MM-dd","${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.codice}").format(_giornoSelezionato)}" : "${_oreProgrammateGiornoAttuale! + 1}"}));
```

Hive boxes are inherently Map<String, dynamic> I think.